# Local and Network Data Manager

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm facing a strange issue i'm not able to track down.

I have a DataManager that is responsable to return data to my TableViewController.
This is the code

```
typealias NewsListCompletionBlock = (Result<NewsList>) -> Void
class DataManager {
    var subManager: DataManagerProtocol
    init() {
        if (Config.isUITests()) {
            subManager = LocalDataManager()
        } else {
            subManager = NetworkDataManager()
        }
    }
}
// MARK: News data manager
extension DataManager {
    func getNewsList(completion:@escaping NewsListCompletionBlock) {
        subManager.performRequest(route: nil, decoder: JSONDecoder(), 
    completion: completion)
    }
}
```

This initializes a subManager based on if we are running UITests or we are running the real application. 
Real application works as expected, but the LocalDataManager returns an error i can't track down.

```
class LocalDataManager: DataManagerProtocol {
@discardableResult
func performRequest<T>(route: APIRouter?, decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder(), completion: @escaping (Result<T>) -> Void) -> DataRequest where T : Decodable {
    let newsListString = """
    {
    "news" : [
        {
            "id": 262,
            "category": "e",
            "title": "Scott Johnson & Paul Fowler Workshop",
            "subtitle": "Wedding Photography Workshop | 20th-24th May 2019, Italy",
            "link": "",
            "date": "2018-08-31"
        }
    ]
    }
    """
    if let jsonData = newsListString.data(using: .utf8)
    {
        let result :Result<NewsList>
        do {
            let newsListObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(NewsList.self, from: jsonData)
            result = Result.success(newsListObject)
        } catch {
            result = Result.failure(NSError(domain: "", code: 123, userInfo: nil))
        }
        completion(result)
    }
}
}
```

This is the code of the LocalDataManager. As you can see i simulate the call of the completion block providing dummy data, but when i compile i get

```
DataManager/LocalDataManager.swift:38:24: Cannot convert value of type 'Result<NewsList>' to expected argument type 'Result<_>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using the `NewsList` explicitly in the place of generic parameter.

Changing the code to follows will work.

```
if let jsonData = newsListString.data(using: .utf8)
    {
        let result :Result<T>
        do {
            let newsListObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: jsonData)
            result = Result.success(newsListObject)
        } catch {
            result = Result.failure(NSError(domain: "", code: 123, userInfo: nil))
        }
        completion(result)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. Now i have to understand why i can't use the explicit type

Comment: Glad it worked, As for why you can't use explicit type inside the method is, the method is written as generic. simple as that. You can use this method for any object given the object confirms the "Decodable" protocol.